# Custom session variables persisting after deletion

Tags: session, drupal, persistence

I'm having a bit of trouble with Drupal 7 and removing session variables I've set.

Things work as expecting when adding an item (via: `$_SESSION['products']['p123'] = 'my product'`) and then removing (via: `unset($_SESSION['products']['p123'])` ) - which would leave me with an empty`$_SESSION['products']` array.

But when I attempt to add another item (such as `$_SESSION['products']['pABC'] = 'another product'`), I would suddenly have both `'p123'` and `'pABC'` as keys in my `$_SESSION['products']` array, even after the initial deletion of `'p123'`.

Do I have to explicitly tell Drupal 7 that I've deleted an item out of my SESSIONS and to save that change?  I hadn't had this issue using Drupal 6.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was because of shifting from HTTP to HTTPS.

I was making my additions on a page served over HTTP, and my deletions on a page served by HTTPS.  It seems that drupal keeps separate session variables for both secure and insecure connections, and will push the insecure session to secure when that transition is made.